# reading from rtsp stream on mac os x using popen and read is failing

Tags: xcode, macos, ffmpeg, popen, rtsp

I am generating an *rtsp* stream using *gstreamer* in an *iOS* app and trying to use *ffmpeg* in a Mac OS X audio driver that I wrote using XCode to strip the audio out of the stream and then pump the audio to *Skype* or *Zoom* or whatever.  All the code is written in the **'C'** old-fashioned programming language.  I do get a **FILE*** that is not **NULL** back from a **popen** function call to execute *ffmpeg* on the input *rtsp* stream.  But once I get that **FILE*** object and try to read binary data from it, it returns that zero bytes have been read.  Here is the code:

```
    FILE *readPipeFromFFMPEG = popen("Contents/MacOS/ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.30:8554/test -vn -acodec copy -flush_packets pipe:1", "r+");

    int pipeFD = fileno(readPipeFromFFMPEG);
    
    char *buffer = (char*)calloc(inIOBufferFrameSize * 8, 1);

    numBytesRead = read(pipeFD, buffer, inIOBufferFrameSize * 8);

    free(buffer);

    pclose(readPipeFromFFMPEG);
```

but **numBytesRead** is always coming back as zero.  Does anybody have any clue what I need to do to get this working properly?  It seems like maybe a permissions issue where I do not have permission to read from the stream?  Or maybe my *ffmpeg* parameters are incorrect?  I am able to open up the stream in VLC and OBS Studio no problem and it displays the video frames and plays the audio.  I am **really** stuck I need help!  I must be missing something totally obvious because when I run OBS Studio or VLC it shows in the iPhone app the requests from the client because it prints out information that the audio and video packets are being requested but when the audio driver is running nothing is printed out in the iPhone app.

Comment: Is it working when reading from a local file? The `"r+"` supposed to be `"r"` (in Windows `"rb"` in macOS probably `"r"`). Put the `-vn` before the `-i`. Try using `fread(buffer, 1, inIOBufferFrameSize*8, readPipeFromFFMPEG);`. Try reading just 1 byte. Try reading just 1 byte repeatedly in a loop.

Comment: For debugging the RTSP connection, you may try forcing TCP protocol, setting connection timeout and storing the output to local file. You may try using FFmpeg command line first. The following command is not working `ffmpeg -y -rtsp_transport tcp -max_delay 30000000 -vn -i rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4 -acodec copy -t 5 tmp.mkv` (I suppose the stream is off).